# Invalid packaging for parent POM must be "pom" but is "war"

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-war-plugin, maven-ear-plugin

Could anybody suggest me an solution with the following exception. I am going to create a multi-module project. (War, Ear)

pom.xml (war)

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>lu.pgd</groupId>
        <artifactId>WebBusiness</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>WebBusiness-war</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Web Business</name>

    <properties>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>
    </properties>
<build>
        <finalName>webBusiness</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>

                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

pom.xml (ear)

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>lu.pgd</groupId>
        <artifactId>WebBusiness</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>spdv-ear</artifactId>
    <packaging>ear</packaging>
    <name>Project EAR</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>lu.pgd</groupId>
            <artifactId>WebBusiness-war</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>WebBusiness</finalName> 
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <applicationId>WebBusiness</applicationId>
                    <displayName>SPDV (${project.version})</displayName>
                    <modules>
                        <webModule>
                            <groupId>lu.pgd</groupId>
                            <artifactId>WebBusiness-war</artifactId>
                            <contextRoot>/WebBusiness</contextRoot>
                            <moduleId>war</moduleId>
                        </webModule>
                    </modules>
                    <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

pom.xml (parent)

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>lu.pgd</groupId>
    <artifactId>WebBusiness</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Parent Project</name>

    <modules>
        <module>../SPDV_EAR</module>
        <module>../WebBusiness</module>
    </modules>

    <packaging>pom</packaging>
</project>
```

When I tried to Run Maven Project Parent (Clean+Install) I got error like :

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] Invalid packaging for parent POM lu.pgd:WebBusiness:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT, must be "pom" but is "war" @ lu.pgd:WebBusiness:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT, C:\dev\lu\pgd\WebBusiness\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\WebBusiness-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom, line 7, column 13
[ERROR] Invalid packaging for parent POM lu.pgd:WebBusiness:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT, must be "pom" but is "war" @ lu.pgd:WebBusiness:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT, C:\dev\lu\pgd\WebBusiness\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\WebBusiness-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom, line 7, column 13
 @ 
[ERROR] The build could not read 2 projects -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project lu.pgd:ccpd-ear:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT (C:\Users\x279\workspace\SPDV_EAR\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Invalid packaging for parent POM lu.pgd:WebBusiness:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT, must be "pom" but is "war" @ lu.pgd:WebBusiness:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT, C:\dev\lu\pgd\WebBusiness\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\WebBusiness-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom, line 7, column 13
[ERROR]   The project lu.pgd:WebBusiness-war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT (C:\Users\x279\workspace\WebBusiness\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Invalid packaging for parent POM lu.pgd:WebBusiness:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT, must be "pom" but is "war" @ lu.pgd:WebBusiness:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT, C:\dev\lu\pgd\WebBusiness\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\WebBusiness-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom, line 7, column 13
```

Could anybody help me here to understand what is going wrong here please ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: For a multi-module project it is important to know your folder structure, can you add that to your question please

Comment: Yes I added picture

Comment: I'm not sure why you added a picture with some JSON value, but it's definitely not the folder structure of your multi module project ;)

Comment: Looolll  I am sorry ... it is mistake ..;

Comment: It's still not really the folder structure how the projects within the multi module project are arranged, it's only the projects within Eclipse. A picture of your file browser would be a lot more helping then the project structures ;)

Comment: Ok, edited it , .. It is ok ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154243/discussion-between-funfried-and-user1814879).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the folder structure for a multi-module project is like this:

```
- parent-project-folder
  - pom.xml (parent-project)
  - submodule-project-folder
    - pom.xml (submodule-project)
  - another-submodule-project-folder
    - pom.xml (another-submodule-project)
```

Then the parent definition you have would be fine, but you have the parent project next to your submodules, so you need to configure a bit more.

Try adding relativePath to your parent specifications:

```
<parent>
   <groupId>...
   ...
   <relativePath>path/to/your/parent/pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
```

Answer (score 4):

Copy your modules SPDV_EAR and WebBusiness into the parent project folder (ccpd). Then change the modules tag in the parent pom to:

```
<modules>
    <module>SPDV_EAR</module>
    <module>WebBusiness</module>
</modules>
```

Also in your parent pom change

```
<artifactId>WebBusiness</artifactId>
```

to

```
<artifactId>ccpd</artifactId>
```

In your war (WebBusiness):

```
  <parent>
    <groupId>lu.pgd</groupId>
    <artifactId>ccpd</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>WebBusiness</artifactId>
```

In you ear:

```
 <parent>
    <groupId>lu.pgd</groupId>
    <artifactId>ccpd</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>SPDV_EAR</artifactId>
```

So your folder names match your project names.

Comment: You probably should fix your naming. Folder name and project name should match.

Comment: Yes, I do it, that's the same name .. I added picture in my question you can check

Comment: Error that I got : `[ERROR]     Child module C:\Users\xsac4279\workspace\ccpd\pom.xml of C:\Users\xsac4279\workspace\ccpd\pom.xml forms aggregation cycle C:\Users\xsac4279\workspace\ccpd\pom.xml -> C:\Users\xsac4279\workspace\ccpd\pom.xml
`

Comment: So let me get this straight:

ccpd is the parent project
CCPD_EAR is the ear
WebBusiness is the war

This naming does not match the naming in the poms

Comment: Humm ../ccpd is the name of project parent ( the war project is WebBusiness and ear is SPDV_EAR)

Comment: Okay in the ccpd folder there is also a CCPD_EAR and another WebBusiness Folder. What is the purpose?

Comment: Okay, I have 3 folders .. ccpd folder with pom.xml and I would like that be my parent ... and I have WebBusiness and SPDV-EAR that I would like that be child